# why is it that my compiler gives me error when working with dynamically allocated memory in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, dereference

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;

vector<long long> count_inv(vector<long long> &left, vector<long long> &right, int &count);

vector<long long> split(vector<long long> &A, int &count)
{
    if (A.size() == 1)
        return A;
    else
    {
        int mid = A.size() / 2;
        int umid = A.size() - mid;
        vector<long long> *left, *right;
        left = new vector<long long>(mid);
        right = new vector<long long>(umid);
        for (int i = 0;i < mid;i++)
            *left[i] = A[i];
        for (int i = mid, j = 0;i < A.size();i++, j++)
            *right[j] = A[i];
        split(*left, count);
        split(*right, count);
        left->push_back(LLONG_MAX);
        right->push_back(LLONG_MAX);
        vector<long long> C = count_inv(*left, *right, count);
        return C;
    }
}

vector<long long> count_inv(vector<long long> &left, vector<long long> &right, int &count)
{
    vector<long long> *merged;
    merged = new vector<long long>(left.size() + right.size() - 2);
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    while (i + j != left.size() + right.size() - 2)
    {
        if (left[i] < right[j])
        {
            *merged[k] = left[i];
            i++;k++;
        }
        else if (left[i] > right[j])
        {
            *merged[k] = right[j];
            j++;k++;count++;
        }
        else
        {
            *merged[k] = left[i];
            *merged[k + 1] = right[j];
            i++;j++;k += 2;
        }
    }
    return *merged;
}

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);

    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--)
    {
        cout << endl;
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        vector<long long> A(n);
        for (int i = 0;i < n;i++)
            cin >> A[i];
        int count = 0;
        vector<long long> S = split(A, count);
        cout << count << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the code above required some dynamic memory allocation, so i did so with the new key in c++, however the compiler gives me the following error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0349   no operator "*" matches these operands
```

in all the lines I've used "*" to deference the dynamically allocated memory,namely in lines 23,25,44,49,54,55.

Comment: Shortly vector is not an object, but interface for manipulations with arrays.

Comment: You normally don't need `new vector`. You certainly don't need it in this program. Rewrite to use `std::vector` directly without any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the explanation for the specific problem you're seeing is that you're not dereferencing the pointer with the operator you think you are:

```
*left[i]
```

This takes the _i_th element of what the compiler thinks is an array of `vector<long long>` and then tries to dereference it with a unary `*` which clearly isn't going to work. You can fix this simply by bracketing it like this: `(*left)[i]`.

However, there are deeper problems with your code. Allocating standard containers on the heap with `new` is often a sign of someone who doesn't understand how to make use of the C++ standard library. You say *"the code above required some dynamic memory allocation"*, but this is probably not true!

Take a look at this:

```
vector<long long> count_inv(vector<long long> &left, vector<long long> &right, int &count)
{
    vector<long long> *merged;
    // snip
    merged = new vector<long long>(left.size() + right.size() - 2);
    return *merged;
}
```

Leaving aside the fact that this is going to leak memory, you could just do this instead:

```
vector<long long> count_inv(vector<long long> &left, vector<long long> &right, int &count)
{
    vector<long long> merged(left.size() + right.size() - 2);
    // snip
    return merged;
}
```

and it would work just as well. You could probably do with spending a little more time learning about the best way to use the standard containers.

Comment: I don't have any good suggestions, but there are plenty of coding forums out there with people who'd have lots of opinions on this subject. If you're not already a member of one, that might be worth doing, too.

Answer (score 3):

Operator `[]` has higher [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than operator `*`. So `*left[i]` means "take index `i` from `left` and then dereference it." What you actually wanted was "dereference `left` and then take index `i` from the result", which would be expressed as `(*left)[i]` instead.

Same for the other vector pointers: `(*right)[i]`, `(*merged)[i]`

Although, really, there's no reason to use dynamically allocated here, and because you are calling `new` without any corresponding `delete`s, you are leaking memory. You either need to `delete` the dynamically allocated `vector` objects before returning from functions `split` and `count_inv`, or more sensibly, just define vectors `left`, `right` and `merged` as automatic (local) variables, as you do already for vector `C`.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have pointed out, the basic syntactic problem is that your assumptions about how `*symbol[i]` is interpreted is not correct. It might do well (as I'd done for years) to print out the operator precedence table and post it within eye-level, wherever you are coding.

Here is one for ya: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence